# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference using ReactFragment

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am attempting to connect my current android application to a React Native component when clicking . I have the following code failing:

Fragment.java

```
reactNativeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            Fragment reactNativeFragment = new ReactFragment.Builder()
                    .setComponentName("ReactNativeProject")
                    .build(); //Failing in here line 138
            
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.loading_view, reactNativeFragment,"tag")
                    .commit();

        }
```

I understand that the component set under `setComponentName` is the name of the project included in index.js:

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

which in my case is located under app.json:

```
{
  "name": "ReactNativeProject",
  "displayName": "ReactNativeProject"
}
```

The error is the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
at com.facebook.react.ReactFragment.newInstance(ReactFragment.java:54)
at com.facebook.react.ReactFragment.-$$Nest$smnewInstance(Unknown Source:0)
at com.facebook.react.ReactFragment$Builder.build(ReactFragment.java:214)
at com.example.reactnative.Fragment$1.onClick(Fragment.java:138)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Would you know what could be the issue when invoking build() in ReactFragment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to set Fabric which is the only boolean parameter in here:

```
   public static class Builder { 
  
     @Nullable String mComponentName; 
     @Nullable Bundle mLaunchOptions; 
     @Nullable Boolean mFabricEnabled; 
  
     public Builder() { 
       mComponentName = null; 
       mLaunchOptions = null; 
       mFabricEnabled = null; 
     }
```

Your call should include setFabricEnabled:

```
Fragment reactNativeFragment = new ReactFragment.Builder()
                    .setComponentName("ReactNativeProject")
                    .setLaunchOptions(getLaunchOptions("test message"))
                    .setFabricEnabled(true)
                    .build();
```